# CloudFlare - prompted for "attention required"

Tags: malware, virus, macos, cloudflare

I am getting a *CloudFlare - attention required / security check* prompt on most of the sites I visit through my Macbook running OS X Yosemite, these sites work perfectly on other devices (such as iPad, iPhone, Android and Windows based laptop) connected via the same network/WiFi.

I have tried many anti-viruses and malware scanners but nothing found so far.

Any clues?

Comment: In any case, it would be a good idea to do a packet capture and see what's your computer is really doing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

Cloudflare has stored cookies from your macbook, you may have used proxy or violated something earlier and cloudflare stored your cookies, and the cookie is same every time you visit. So everytime you visit webs behind cloudflare it says attention. Try deleting browser and system cookies and try that website again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're using a proxy such as TOR, these IP addresses often get used to DDOS websites or perform other malicious activities, hence the block.

Comment: No, I am using Chrome and there's no proxy set-up done. I have tried different browsers but no luck so far.

Comment: Shoot, could it be that I tried to use Tor just because, earlier this day?

Comment: @user300375 No, that would only happen if you set yourself to act as a Tor exit node. If you didn't (you would know if you did), then Cloudflare would only provide Tor blocks when you are actively using Tor.